# Ethereum Derivation path(m'/44'/60'/0/'0/n)

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, hd-wallets

when we create ethereum HD wallet through a mnemonic phrase, we always need derivation path. is it fix for a particular currency or we can put whatever we like (ex- m/0/n, m/4/3/n or anything else)?

Answer (score 1):

If your wallet allows it yes.

There are some wallet that only use a predefined path, so if you try to import a seed they will not show any ether/tokens that are in another path.

If you use other path you should be aware that changing path might alter your security considerations, ie consider [hardened keys](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37826/best-practices-for-hardened-keys-in-hd-wallets).

Also some of the places in the path derivation have explicit meaning like coinType and there's a [register](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md) for common coins.

Comment: I am aware about predefined path format and the register(m/44'/0'/account'/change/index). Do i need to follow the proper format ? Or just i can just start creating child addresses by any path like m/0/1/n here n=0,1,2,3...

Comment: looking for more clarity on this topic

Comment: If your wallet allows it you can use any path. Standards were defined for a reason but if you do not care about compatibility with others it should be fine to use any path.